# how to move specific part of a 2d array to either left right up or down?

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I know that you can move an array with NumPy so if you use np.roll you can shift array to right or to the left. I was wondering how to move a specific set of values with in the array to either left right up or down.

for example
[image]

if I wanted to move what is circled in red to the left how would i be able to move that and nothing else?

Comment: how about using indexes like `array[y1:y2 , x1-1:x2-1] = array[y1:y2,x1:x2]`. But first shomehow you have to get coordinates of this region.

Comment: since it is a 2d array I use for loop to find the position where the value is greater than its surrounding so it will give me x[1,10],[1,10]. so that would be if I wanted to move the top left corner. hope that help explain

Comment: i don't know what means `x[1,10],[1,10]` - you need `x1,y2,width,height` for region which you wan to move (or `x1,y1` `x2,y2`) - and if you want to move it in corner `[0,0]` then you need `array[0:(0+height),0:(0+width)] = array[y1:(y1+height),x1:(x1+width)]`. It simply gets some region from array - `region = array[y1:(y1+height),x1:(x1+width)]` and it put this region in new place `array[0:(0+height),0:(0+width)] = region`

Comment: so what i meant is I have this 2d array lets say x= 
([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 ], 
 [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 ]])
so x[0][1] = 1 and x[0][2] = 2 I want to shift element from the first 1, 2, 1 in the first index and in the second index so x[0][1], x[0][2]x[0][3] and x[1][1], x[1][2]x[1][3] I want to shift them over to the left or right or even upper or down. in this case up and down does not work since y on goes from 0-1 but for larger array.

Comment: you should add it in question at start - and maybe you would get answer few hours ago.

Comment: do you know how use `slice` - ie. `region = x[0:2][1:4]` to get subarray `[[1,2,1],[1,2,1]]`? And later assing it in other place `x[0:2][0:3] = region` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy` can use `slice` to get subarray and later assing it in different place

```
import numpy as np

x = [
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 ],
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 ]
]

arr = np.array(x)

print(arr)

subarr = arr[0:2,1:4]  # get values
print(subarr)

arr[0:2,0:3] = subarr  # put in new place

print(arr)
```

Result:

```
[[0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 1 0]
 [0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 1 0]]

[[1 2 1]
 [1 2 1]]

[[1 2 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 0]
 [1 2 1 1 0 0 1 2 1 0]]
```

It keeps original values in `[0][1]`, `[1][1]`. If you want remove them then you could copy subarray, set `zero` in original place, and put copy in new place

```
import numpy as np

x = [
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 ],
  [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0 ]
]

arr = np.array(x)

print(arr)

subarr = arr[0:2,1:4].copy()  # duplicate values
print(subarr)

arr[0:2,1:4] = 0  # remove original values

arr[0:2,0:3] = subarr  # put in new place

print(arr)
```

Result

```
[[0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 1 0]
 [0 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 1 0]]

[[1 2 1]
 [1 2 1]]

[[1 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0]
 [1 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0]]
```